# Mysterious Hierarchy ribbon group on calendar view?

Tags: ribbon, farm-solution

I have created a SP solution that had a list and custom action originally based on an Events list (id 106).  It was asked that we change this to a new ID as per SPCAF warning (Define Type of ListTemplate greater than 10000).  That is fine, but now the calendar.aspx view does not have an events tab.  I Switched the custom action to use the Item's tab and all works as expected... except there is a random new group "Hierarchy" with options to Outdent, indent and show/hide subitems.  I have no idea what is causing this group to appear.  I cannot find it anywhere else on this list and it's views or on other lists/views.

Does anyone know how to hide this group in my SP Solution? Or alternatively, does anyone know how to use a custom template type and still get the events tab?  The list template does use the events content type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The event list isn't designed to be modified. Only based types are modifiable via the feature framework directly.

Being on premises this leaves you with three options.

1) Create the list in full as you need it to be with the feature framework. In this case probably not going to work depending on your requirements. (Lowest recommendation)

2) Deploy a base Events list and modify it via a feature receiver via custom code. (Good recommendation)

3) Deploy using the add-in model. See the [office pnp github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP) for more details. (Most future proof recommendation)